# while using typescript and setting the value of a class variable as 1 I got an extra output of undefined and after that value 1 was printed

Tags: typescript

I have just started to learn typescript and wrote this piece of code

```
 class A {

        name = function() {
            console.log( "inside Name" );

        };
        data: string;
    }

    var a: A = new A();
    console.log( a.name() )
    a.data = "1";
    console.log( "my data value=" + a.data );
```

and I was expecting a output like this
inside Name
my data value=1
but not sure how I got an extra undefined in the output like this

inside Name
undefined
my data value=1

can anyone help me understand why it is coming?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fazz2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Founded the answer it seems that the function itself returns an undefined if we have not provided anything in the function so ran the above code with this extra statement and got this as output

```
 name = function() {
        console.log( "inside Name" );
        return 'returing from name';
    };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFq0c.png)